# Module not found error upon creating a new Component using angular cli

Tags: angular-cli, angular-components

I am building a sample app using Angular cli. When I create a new Component and add it in the module.ts file, upon ng serve I get this message in the terminal  "ERROR in ./src/app/server/server.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in 'D:\angular\my-app\src\app\server'"
here is my code:

module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ServerComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

server.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sever',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['']
})

export class ServerComponent {}
```

And its a simple html tags that I have used in the markup templates. I browsed for the solution, where couple of them mention it could be the issue with the path or could be the issue with respect to the IDE that the user was using. Is is really to do with the IDE configuration or with something to do with the angular setup? It will be a great help if I can have some comments on this.

Comment: did you create the component with ng g c componentname?  i believe it automatically adds it to the module if you create the component that way

Comment: also did you run npm install to pull down all the dependecies?

Comment: @JBoothUA The mistake I made was that I have mentioned "styleUrls: [' ']" as empty, I could have removed that parameter from the meta data list altogether. Then it worked as expected.